# Using Google Play Licensing In a Nativescript App

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, nativescript

I'm deploying my Nativescript app to Google Play and would like to use the Play Stores licensing tools so that the app can't be distributed in a malicious way. Is it possible to use these tools with a Nativescript app currently? It seems I need to use the Play services SDK but not sure how I can approach this. Support for the play services in NS are seem lacking. I'm just looking for some guidance and a decent approach.

I found an npm package for nativescript-google-sdk but that seems purely maps focused. It also hasn't been updated in quite some time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the moment you upload your APK in the Google Play Store as mentioned in [Native script docs](http://docs.nativescript.org/publishing/publishing-android-apps), you'll have the option to configure the [Licensing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/setting-up.html) there. So you shouldn't worry. This [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324963/how-can-i-implement-google-play-licensing-for-an-android-app) might offer additional info as well.

Comment: Thanks, I know that once the application is in the Play Store I can get the licensing info but there are several other steps that need to be made within the app code in order to insure that the licensing check is made. This is where my concern is due to the nature of the app being written in JS.

Comment: You should cross the bridge when you get there, publish your beta app and see where it goes. Anyway, check this [github post](https://github.com/NativeScript/android-runtime/issues/440) it might help, especially if your concern is obfuscation of code.

Comment: I have actually already deployed the build to the Play Store and set up the beta release.  So I have the licensing key ready but integrating the play services sdk with Nativescript is where the current blocker is.

Comment: If it's not mentioned in the docs, maybe it's not supported yet.