# Purchase Check/Auth for Paid Apps

Tags: android

I'm thinking of releasing a "PRO" (ad-free) version for my android application and I'm worried that the apk would be shared on blogs/crack sites for free distribution

is there a way to add some kind a purchase check? Since the app will be available for purchase only, there should be a way to check the user's purchase history maybe?

If the user hasn't purchased the app and is using it the app would show a message that they haven't bought it properly and would shut down.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that you are looking for is the **App Licensing**. Here is the link that can help you.

[How can I implement Google Play Licensing for an Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324963/how-can-i-implement-google-play-licensing-for-an-android-app)