# Server-side user auth for paid android app

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-play-developer-api, daydream

I am working on an Android app for daydream that is paid and has no login screen.

I want to emulate the user auth flow that I used when developing for Oculus outlined [here](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/platform/latest/concepts/dg-ownership/) in which you first make a local license check, then use the data returned and the userId to make a server-side check from my backend to Google Play's over http/REST.

I can't seem to find a way to get an Android App's userId (or token) in order to make this check without logins. The current path I am heading down is one in which uses the sorely outdated License Verification Library (for local checks) as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324963/how-can-i-implement-google-play-licensing-for-an-android-app) and then uses the [Google Play Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/getting_started) to preform a server check.

Is this the proper way to approach this, or is there a better/more modern way to do this? One that perhaps models after the Oculus flow more? Additionally, I want to limit the permissions I need to request the user for, since with Daydream VR, the user must remove the headset to accept permissions at the moment.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer) as it's about handling OAuth on the server side. The flow you've shown is also a bit similar to the [Web server applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#webserver) diagram.