# How to use Google Play licensing step by step with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

Tried with one example, however, errors below occurred.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lng.xxxcom.lng.xxx.MainPage}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService }

Appreciated a lot with a step-by-step example.

Comment: when using the doCheck(); from the library of the link , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324963/how-can-i-implement-google-play-licensing-for-an-android-app

Comment: Where is your code for starting the service? Reads like you are using an implicit intent (i.e. action string) and it wants you to start it with an explicit intent (i.e. class name)

Comment: private void doCheck() {

        didCheck = false;
        checkingLicense = true;
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

        mChecker.checkAccess(mLicenseCheckerCallback);
    }              the code above is to access to the library of listening. so the problem is on the checkAccess();  just like the link above shows

Comment: you should edit your question to add the code. You need to find the line of code that says `startService` if it is a library that is doing then, then it seems a problem in the library