# Official documentation for licensing response codes as int

Tags: android

I'm implementing the [licensing](https://github.com/google/play-licensing/blob/master/README.txt) in my App but I didn't found an official list of response codes.

The piece of script that return the code (`int policyReason`) is this:

```
private class MyLicenseCheckerCallback implements LicenseCheckerCallback {
    public void allow(int policyReason) {
        if (isFinishing()) {
            // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
            return;
        }
        // Should allow user access.
        displayResult(getString(R.string.allow));
    }

    public void dontAllow(int policyReason) {
        if (isFinishing()) {
            // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
            return;
        }
        displayResult(getString(R.string.dont_allow));
        // Should not allow access. In most cases, the app should assume
        // the user has access unless it encounters this. If it does,
        // the app should inform the user of their unlicensed ways
        // and then either shut down the app or limit the user to a
        // restricted set of features.
        // In this example, we show a dialog that takes the user to a deep
        // link returned by the license checker.
        // If the reason for the lack of license is that the service is
        // unavailable or there is another problem, we display a
        // retry button on the dialog and a different message.
        displayDialog(policyReason == Policy.RETRY);
    }

    public void applicationError(int errorCode) {
        if (isFinishing()) {
            // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
            return;
        }
        // This is a polite way of saying the developer made a mistake
        // while setting up or calling the license checker library.
        // Please examine the error code and fix the error.
        String result = String.format(getString(R.string.application_error), errorCode);
        displayResult(result);
    }
}
```

I found these [here](https://www.realglitch.com/2013/05/android-licensing-error-codes/) (unofficial, the link provided points to an official documentation without int codes):

> ```
> Response Code                 Value
> Licensed                      256
> Not_licensed                  561
> Error_Server_Failure          291
> Error_Contacting_Server       291
> Error_Not_Market_Managed      3
> Error_Invalid_Package_Name    1
> Error_Non_Matching_UID        2
> ```

and these [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18325731/2342558) (unofficial, without link to a official documentation with int codes):

> ```
> LICENSED                   = Hex: 0x0100, Decimal: 256
> NOT_LICENSED               = Hex: 0x0231, Decimal: 561
> RETRY                      = Hex: 0x0123, Decimal: 291
> LICENSED_OLD_KEY           = Hex: 0x2,    Decimal: 2
> ERROR_NOT_MARKET_MANAGED   = Hex: 0x3,    Decimal: 3
> ERROR_SERVER_FAILURE       = Hex: 0x4,    Decimal: 4
> ERROR_OVER_QUOTA           = Hex: 0x5,    Decimal: 5
> ERROR_CONTACTING_SERVER    = Hex: 0x101,  Decimal: 257
> ERROR_INVALID_PACKAGE_NAME = Hex: 0x102,  Decimal: 258 
> ERROR_NON_MATCHING_UID     = Hex: 0x103,  Decimal: 259
> ```

But in the official documentation for the [`LicenseValidator`](https://github.com/google/play-licensing/blob/master/lvl_library/src/main/java/com/google/android/vending/licensing/LicenseValidator.java) class there are these:

```
// Server response codes.
private static final int LICENSED = 0x0;
private static final int NOT_LICENSED = 0x1;
private static final int LICENSED_OLD_KEY = 0x2;
private static final int ERROR_NOT_MARKET_MANAGED = 0x3;
private static final int ERROR_SERVER_FAILURE = 0x4;
private static final int ERROR_OVER_QUOTA = 0x5;

private static final int ERROR_CONTACTING_SERVER = 0x101;
private static final int ERROR_INVALID_PACKAGE_NAME = 0x102;
private static final int ERROR_NON_MATCHING_UID = 0x103;
```

(edit) For example, `policyReason` may returns `291` and `256` but these aren't in `LicenseValidator` (`0x101` = `257`, `0x102 =`258`,`0x103`=`259`).

Where I can find an **official documentation** that contains the list of int's response codes to rely on?

I already searched in the `lvl-library` module but without success.

(edit2) Thanks to @Mir Milad Hosseiny's answer now I know precisely where to find these int codes. But now I have a doubt: why does allow should return RETRY or NOT_LICENSED and dontAllow RETRY and LICENSED? Because of their names they shoudn't return nothing than respectively LICENSED and NOT_LICENSED/RETRY. I must know how to properly handle the case when the user did download my App from Google Play. **[I asked a dedicated question about that here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59804881/2342558)**.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what is the problem with the codes provided in `LicenseValidator`? Convert them to int and you are good to go.

Comment: @Daniel The values returned by `policyReason` are different. For example, policyReason may returns 291 and 256 but these aren't in LicenseValidator (0x101 = 257, 0x102 =258,0x103=259`).

Comment: Have you checked the `verify` method in the `LicenseValidator` class? It maps all `LicenseValidator` server response codes to the `Policy` reason codes and `LicenseCheckerCallback` application error codes.

Comment: as mentioned in the source code of `Policy`, you can define a custom policy with your custom codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Licensing Reference](https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/licensing-reference) official page on the Android Developers website.

**Update**
There are 3 callback methods on the [LicenseCheckerCallback](https://github.com/google/play-licensing/blob/06236264512be131c1d729d260c0467253abf75d/lvl_library/src/main/java/com/google/android/vending/licensing/LicenseCheckerCallback.java) class.

**1. public void allow(int reason)**

> @param reason Policy.LICENSED or Policy.RETRY typically. (although in theory the policy can return Policy.NOT_LICENSED here as well)

**2. public void dontAllow(int reason)**

> @param reason Policy.NOT_LICENSED or Policy.RETRY. (although in theory the policy can return Policy.LICENSED here as well --- perhaps the call to the LVL took too long, for example)

**3. public void applicationError(int errorCode)**

> Error in application code. Caller did not call or set up license checker correctly. Should be considered fatal.

For first and second methods, input value `reason` is one of the `Policy.LICENSED`, `Policy.NOT_LICENSED` and `Policy.RETRY` values which are available on [Policy](https://github.com/google/play-licensing/blob/06236264512be131c1d729d260c0467253abf75d/lvl_library/src/main/java/com/google/android/vending/licensing/Policy.java) class source code as below:

```
/**
 * LICENSED means that the server returned back a valid license response
 */
public static final int LICENSED = 0x0100;
/**
 * NOT_LICENSED means that the server returned back a valid license response
 * that indicated that the user definitively is not licensed
 */
public static final int NOT_LICENSED = 0x0231;
/**
 * RETRY means that the license response was unable to be determined ---
 * perhaps as a result of faulty networking
 */
public static final int RETRY = 0x0123;
```

For the third method, error codes are available on LicenseCheckerCallback class source code as below:

```
/** Application error codes. */
public static final int ERROR_INVALID_PACKAGE_NAME = 1;
public static final int ERROR_NON_MATCHING_UID = 2;
public static final int ERROR_NOT_MARKET_MANAGED = 3;
public static final int ERROR_CHECK_IN_PROGRESS = 4;
public static final int ERROR_INVALID_PUBLIC_KEY = 5;
public static final int ERROR_MISSING_PERMISSION = 6;
```

Also, You can check [LicenseValidator](https://github.com/google/play-licensing/blob/06236264512be131c1d729d260c0467253abf75d/lvl_library/src/main/java/com/google/android/vending/licensing/LicenseValidator.java) and [LicenseChecker](https://github.com/google/play-licensing/blob/89ebdfcf52562018ff4c366055f0e35393919763/lvl_library/src/main/java/com/google/android/vending/licensing/LicenseChecker.java) classes source code to check passed input values to these 3 methods are consistent with their documentations.

Comment: Next time just [edit] your post instead of deleting it and re-answering.

Comment: as you can see in the link you provided, there aren't the `int`s for the constants... that is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I have a doubt: why does `allow` should return `RETRY` or `NOT_LICENSED` and `dontAllow` `RETRY` and `LICENSED`? Because of their names they shoudn't return nothing than respectively `LICENSED` and `NOT_LICENSED`/`RETRY`. I must know how to properly handle the case when the user did download my App from Google Play.

Comment: You can use different policies ([StrictPolicy](https://github.com/google/play-licensing/blob/46733234c722e0ac49099f26617f2b4afe8c9ae0/lvl_library/src/main/java/com/google/android/vending/licensing/StrictPolicy.java) or [ServerManagedPolicy](https://github.com/google/play-licensing/blob/46733234c722e0ac49099f26617f2b4afe8c9ae0/lvl_library/src/main/java/com/google/android/vending/licensing/ServerManagedPolicy.java) or any custom Policy) when you are creating an instance of `LicenseChecker`. This is the reason that `allow` could return `RETRY` or even `NOT_LICENSED`.

Comment: For correct implementation, follow the [LicenseCheckerCallback](https://github.com/google/play-licensing/blob/46733234c722e0ac49099f26617f2b4afe8c9ae0/lvl_library/src/main/java/com/google/android/vending/licensing/LicenseCheckerCallback.java) interface documentation.